# Liferay - Eclipse IDE- Duplicate unique value declared for identity constraint "tag-name-uniqeness" of element "taglib"

Tags: eclipse, liferay, portlet, liferay-7

I use liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga4 and eclipse IDE for developing a portlet.

I just created a liferay project using liferay plugin project in eclipse and I got a bunch of errors like this
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fERr.png)

The error is in liferay-ui.tld file in tld directory. [this is the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZUAt.png)

I don't have any idea how to deal with it.Please help me.

Comment: What have you actually done? How did you set up your project, what files are included? Are you using the Ant-based plugins-sdk, maven, gradle or Liferay Workspace?

Comment: Setting up the project was straightforward new liferay plugin project with mvc portlet framework. It is an Ant-based plugins-sdk.

The project has a docroot,test folders and other defaults files and folders.

Comment: That error dissapeared when I deleted the project and created a new one.